# avoid non constant expression in android

Tags: java, android, adt

There is a new thing since ADT 14, it's called non-constant expression: migration necessary.
Which cause that I can't do stuff like this:

```
TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text);
```

Or this:

```
getRessources().getDrawable(R.drawable.icon);
```

What I have to do to make it work now?

Comment: Sometime it works sometimes it doesn't work. What is this ?

Comment: Please make your question more clear.

Comment: for example i can't make : Drawable picture = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.robot);

Answer (score 3):

You must refactor your code since in library projects, the R fields are no longer constants(not `final`).  See http://tools.android.com/tips/non-constant-fields for details and examples on how to fix the issue.

Basically, you need to change your `switch` statements to `if-else` since you cannot switch over a non-constant.

Also, this is only for library projects.  regular android projects do not require this change.

After you make the changes be sure to clean and refresh your project as some errors/warnings may linger.

Answer (score 1):

In Eclipse,
Click On Project -> Properties -> Android

and uncheck if true "Is Library" option.